# C# cmd command throwing exception

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create a cmd command from code, the command is:

```
Tools.IRSGenBuild\\Build.bat bah
```

This should create a file from the bah file using the Build.bat

I'm not femilier with cmd command but the man who showed me how to use the command set the folder using a command:

```
cd c:\\Users\\Sam\\Desktop\\FinalProject\\IRSGen
```

What I did in my code is:

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process processStart = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfoStart = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfoStart.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfoStart.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfoStart.Arguments = "/C cd c:\\Users\\Sam\\Desktop\\FinalProject\\IRSGen";
        processStart.StartInfo = startInfoStart;
        processStart.Start();

            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = "/C Tools.IRSGenBuild\\Build.bat bah";
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();

            Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\FinalProject\IRSGen\Tools.IRSGen\Products\Development\Assemblies");
```

The last line is to open the folder of the .bat products.

I'm getting an exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

**Edit:**

This is now my code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\FinalProject\IRSGen";
            startInfo.Arguments = @"Tools.IRSGen\Build\Build.bat bah";
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();

            Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\FinalProject\IRSGen\Tools.IRSGen\Products");
```

And it's not working, when i run it from cmd it work fine. what am i doing wrong? (The exception was thrown because i tried to open the folder that was not created, the problem is in the cmd command)

Comment: First chance exceptions are exceptions that may or may not be handled for you in a try-catch block inside the framework code. If you turn on [Just My Code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdnstudents/archive/2013/12/02/visual-studio-tips-and-tricks-easier-debugging-with-just-my-code.aspx) does your problem go away?

Comment: The first `cmd` instance is useless, as it just changes the working directory and exits. Furthermore, if you want a different working directory, you can just supply one in the `ProcessStartInfo` instance.

Comment: If you need to do a CD (change directory) you must put it into the first line of the .bat file as the cd will not persist from one cmd process to the next.

Comment: Can you give an example on how to write the CD ?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I turned on just my code and now i see the problem more clearly. I'm guessing the problem is that i didn't preform the change directory correctly. How can I do that?

Comment: What is the exception you get now? FileNotFound?

Comment: Now i'm not getting any exception, but the bat file that i'm starting is suppose to create some files and it doesn't happen, there is no problem with the bat (it works fine from cmd) so my guess is that the problem is with in the command that i'm trying to create

Comment: Is there any way to see the command prompt lines? because the bat i'm activating is writing line of success or failure, maybe this could help to debug the problem